# Java classTest error

Tags: java, class

I wrote a class and now I am trying to test it, and I get and error on my class test that says "CylinderTest.java:9: getHeight() in Cylinder cannot be applied to (double)"

Here is the code for my class:

```
public class Cylinder
private double Radius;
private double Height;
public final static double Pi = 3.14159;
// constructor
public Cylinder()
{
    Radius = 0.0;{

    Height = 0.0;
}
// getRaduis method
public double getRadius()
{       
    return Radius;
}
// getHeight method
public double getHeight()
{

    return Height;
}
// setRadius method 
public void setRadius(double r)
{
    Radius = r;
}
// setHeight method
public void setHeight(double h)
{
    Height = h;
}
// getSurfaceArea
public double getBaseArea(double BaseArea)
{
    BaseArea = Radius * Radius * Pi;
    return BaseArea;
}
// getVolume
public double getVolume(double BaseArea, double Volume)
{
    Volume = BaseArea * Height;
    return Volume;
}
// Print
//System.out.println("The volume of the cylinder is " +Volume);
```

}

and here is the code for the classTest:

```
public class CylinderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Cylinder cylinderA = new Cylinder();
        cylinderA.getRadius(3.5);
        cylinderA.getHeight(4.5);
        System.out.println(cylinderA.getVolume());
    }
}
```

The original cylinder class that I wrote compiles fine I am having trouble when I try to compile the classTest. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The getRadius and getHeight functions don't have doubles as parameters, so they can't be called like that. I think you need to use setRadius and setHeight

Answer (score 0):

You're calling your getter method when it looks like you should be calling your setter method:

```
cylinderA.setHeight(4.5); 
//        ^
```

If you really intend to call your getter method, then call it like this:

```
double height = cylinderA.getHeight();
```

because `getHeight` doesn't have any parameters.

Comment: How do I print the volume with out creating a setVolume method in the classCylinder?

Comment: How do I print the volume with out creating a setVolume method in the classCylinder?